# Ctrl-C in bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

How do I implement <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> handling in bash scripts so that the script is interrupted, as well as the currently running command launched by the script?

(Imagine there's a script that executes some long-running command. The user hits <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and interrupts the command, but the script proceeds.) I need it to behave in a way that they are both killed.

Comment: If your OS has job-control enabled, another option would be to stop that script (usually with crtl-z). You can continue that job in background with `bg`, kill it or continue it in foreground with `fg`. See the bash manpage section `JOB CONTROL`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You do this by creating a subroutine you want to call when SIGINT is received, and you need to run `trap 'subroutinename' INT`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

int_handler()
{
    echo "Interrupted."
    # Kill the parent process of the script.
    kill $PPID
    exit 1
}
trap 'int_handler' INT

while true; do
    sleep 1
    echo "I'm still alive!"
done

# We never reach this part.
exit 0
```

Comment: Note that you can also trap on `EXIT` in cases where you have something you want to execute anytime the script exits regardless how it stopped.  (`KILL` excepted, of course.)

Comment: Great, thanks! However, when 'sleep' is killed — the shell could still be able to manage to execute the next command while the trap routine is running: 'echo' in this case... or I'm wrong?

Comment: That should not be possible, no.  It does not perform tasks in parallel.